# ASP.NET dynamically generated event code not running

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, webforms

I'm trying to fix a bug in a web application that dynamically creates buttons with events attached to them. I'm dealing with this man function that gets called from inside a for loop. From the research I've done this way of assigning the event should work, but It doesn't. In fact, on click the button disappears for some reason. Am I assigning the dynamic events wrong or could there be something else entirely going wrong? The "drivers" variable is a panel that the button is created inside.

```
 public void generateDriver(string name, string route, string id)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("A driver has been created!");
    Literal driverLit = new Literal();
    driverLit.Text += "<div class='routeTitle'>";
    driverLit.Text += "<input type='text' id='hiddenID' text='" + id + "' hidden />";
    driverLit.Text += name + "<br>";
    driverLit.Text += route + "<br>";
    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Text = "Remove";
    newButton.ID = id;
    newButton.Click += new EventHandler(RemoveDriver);
    newButton.CssClass = "btn btn-danger";
    drivers.Controls.Add(driverLit);
    drivers.Controls.Add(newButton);
    drivers.Controls.Add(new Literal
    {
        Text = "</div>"
    });
}
public void RemoveDriver(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("An event has been triggered!");
    Button removeBtn = (Button)sender;
    string id = removeBtn.ID;       
    string querystring = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();

    List<string> routes = querystring.Split('-').ToList();
    routes.Remove(id);

    string newQueryString = string.Join("-", routes);

    Response.Redirect("/Orders.aspx?id=" + newQueryString);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So the RemoveDriver method is not being triggered?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. On click it disappears, and nothing is written to the console. It doesn't look like any of my breakpoints are hit there either.

Comment: You have to recreate the dynamic controls every page load, before events are handled, or the event won't have an owner.  It's been a while since I've actively used web forms, but I believe this should be done in the Initialization event, prior to Load. [Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: [Here's a good C# example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317794/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-in-asp-net-by-using-visual-c-net) of dynamic controls with events across postbacks.

Comment: @ps2goat is correct. You need to reconstruct controls and rewire your events during the page's `OnInit` event.

Comment: @ps2goat That is working for me. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I posted this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to recreate the dynamic controls every page load, before events are handled, or the event won't have an owner. This should be done in the Initialization event (the page's `OnInit` event handler), prior to Load.